# Using Hyperspy for reading metadata from Velox EMD dataset of image series

Tags: python

I have a image series/video saved in the Velox EMD file format. I am able to read the video file and see all the frames using Hyperspy. I also am able to see the original metadata. However, I would like to know if there is a way to access the metadata for each frame in the video since during the acquisition of the video, one of the parameters was changed.

Thank you,

cheers,
-cd